# Tag-it CSS is not being applied even though resource has loaded

Tags: jquery, css

Basically I'm making numerous amounts of AJAX requests to gain data, which I then want to be tagged using [Hailwood's Tagit JS library](https://github.com/hailwood/jQuery-Tagit). Literally everything is working fine except for the fact the CSS is not being applied to the tagged elements. Here is what I'm working with:

```
$("#dataTable tbody tr").each(function() {
    var first = $(this).find("td:first").text();
    var second = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)");

    second.tagit({
        select: true,
        allowNewTags: false,
        placeholder: '',
        tagsChanged: function() {}
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'search.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
        query: first
        },
        success: function(data) {
            second.tagit("fill", data);
        }
    });
});
```

The returned data is being tagged, but the CSS for the tag is not being applied. If this is something like CSS binding how do I resolve it in this context?

Comment: Have you included CSS of this plugin in your page?

Comment: `<link href="css/tag-it.simple-blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` which is the CSS provided on the Github page. I'm using this on a different page of the app and it works fine so I don't understand why the CSS won't load on this page.

Answer (score 0):

For initializing I needed a `ul` to be inside my `td` which I didn't have as I expected tagit to create it for me (not really sure why as on the other page I have made the ul). Solution below that includes not having a pointless `ul` when no results are found:

```
$("#dataTable tbody tr").each(function () {
        var first = $(this).find("td:first").text();
        var second = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)");
        var ulId = '#' + second.find("ul:first").attr('id');

        $(ulId).tagit({
            placeholder: '',
            maxTags: 3,
            tagsChanged: function () {
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: 'search.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                query: first
            },
            success: function(data) {
                data.length > 1 ? $(ulId).tagit("fill", data):second.html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```